# How to configure spring-boot with security for custom SQL schema user-role?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I try to configure spring-boot-security for integrated with my SQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  role     INTEGER            NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (role) REFERENCES user_role (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_role (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  role VARCHAR(10)
);
```

I find many examples of integration database with spring-boot-security and all those examples like this:

```
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
}
```

I don't understand how to work methods `usersByUsernameQuery` and `authoritiesByUsernameQuery`. Why all select by `username`? Where `password`? Password does not need for authentication?

Please, explain to me how this work.
How to connect my DB to security with `configAuthentication()`?

Comment: I think it uses the query to fetch the user object. After it fetches it. then it makes password check.

Comment: @Imran I too think about this. But how to customize it for my case if I don't know how to interact `usersByUsernameQuery` and `authoritiesByUsernameQuery`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your approach you should have to make some changes in order run successfully the querys that are in `usersByUsernameQuery` and `authoritiesByUsernameQuery`.

For example: `usersByUsernameQuery` according to your table definition should be `select username,password,true from users where username=?` because you don't have a enable filed on your users table.

and `authoritiesByUsernameQuery` should be `select u.username, r.role from users u inner join user_roles r on (r.id=u.role) where u.username=?` because one table has the user information and the other the role that is the reason why you should use a join in the query.

Spring authentication let you configure many ways to implement your authetication method, in this case what you put on the question is an a jdbc authentication approach.

When you use jdbc authentication approach is necessary to check the following:

1. Make sure that your `pom.xml` has the jdbc dependency and your database dependency, this example is for h2 database

   ```
     <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
           </dependency>
     <dependency>
           <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
           <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. Define a datasource bean in order to let spring boot knows how to connect to the database

DataSource Bean

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
 public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
     DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
     driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
     driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:~/test2");
     return driverManagerDataSource;

 }
```

3. Then you need to create a class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in order to inject the `DataSource` bean to your `AuthenticationManager` builder, here is where Spring Authentication bind with your database in order to execute the querys to retrieve the user and role data that your already create on your database.

For example:

```
public class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
 DataSource dataSource;

 @Autowired
 public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
```

And finally the `auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)` set the datasource in order to query the user and roles.

**Front end connection to the /login servlet authentication**

First create the view that will consume the `/login` servlet

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
          xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div th:if="${param.error}">
        Invalid username and password.
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
        You have been logged out.
    </div>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
        <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Register the login view

```
@Configuration
    public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        }
    }
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Thank You for You're answering! Generating dataSource, not a problem for me it is done. The issue is customized dataSource for my SQL schema. I write auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource). and now I need to do something but what? When I call .usersByUsernameQuery(...) I get Exception. My SQL schema does not match with expected of spring security.

Comment: ok so you need to know how to connect the login form to authentication, is that?

Comment: I need know how to use `configAuthentication` method and `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` object for validation user's input in the database.

Comment: First login form sends the username and password values, after that the request pass through security filters, at that moment spring authentication will call your authentication builder and the authentication will be send to your database the request through the queries that your define at  `usersByUsernameQuery` and `authoritiesByUsernameQuery`, if the user exists then it will be authenticated of course the password should match in order to pass the authentication process.

Comment: could you share the exception that you get all the stacktrace in order to see where the error comes from

Comment: I go by You're a path. And use You code, its work for me. Thank You. Unfortunately, Exception is lost with old code but You're solution work and its general. Thank You one more time!

Comment: I tried your solution but it still didn't work for me. I have actually 3 tables: user, role and user_role. I still couldn't find where the problem lied on.

Comment: auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
              .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, true "
                    + "from user where username = ?")
              .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user.username, role.role "
                    + "from user "
                    + "inner join user_role on (user.id = user_role.user_id) "
                    + "inner join role on (role.id = user_role.role_id) "
                    + "where user.username = ?");